# Visual studio 2010 color scheme for vs 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, color-scheme

Does anyone know if there exists a color scheme for Visual Studio 2008 so it would look more like the new Visual Studio 2010? If not the whole IDE then at least the "Fonts-Colors" part.

Comment: Do you have a link to a screenshot? I wasn't aware VS2010 had a new color scheme.

Comment: It looks alot more like Expression Blend. Take a look here : http://tinyurl.com/cfx6d7 (kinda small picture... but the best/first i found)

Answer (score 1):

Worst color scheme Microsoft could come up with, Dark Blue looks good for some time but certainly cant live with it for hours at a time, makes me feel im staring at a dumb dark window.(dunno how to explain it but the overall color scheme totally totally sucks, as a developer you cant use that for long)

Comment: I would have hoped they focused on bringing out the code views more and tone down the other panels, palettes and browser windows which right now competes by being as white as the code views... which feels annoying. But I agree the blue border-thingie blows - however, it is darker which is good but, using a specific color is like Office 2007 or Vista/win7 non-aero windows, a big mistake if not configurable... what if I don't like blue? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will have much luck finding such a color scheme, as the "Fonts and Colors" page in the Visual Studio 2008 options dialog deals only with the contents of the code editor.

The colors changed between 2008 and 2010 are *outside* of the code editor, eg on the "background" between the code editor and other internal windows, as illustrated by these sample screen dumps:

**Visual Studio 2008**
[image]
<sub>(source: [visitmix.com](http://visitmix.com/labs/rosetta/images/ftsl/setup/screen3_800.jpg))</sub>

**Visual Studio 2010**
[image]